# Android ListView items not responding when come back from another activity?

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I create a ListView from an ArrayAdapter. Each row of ListView have an ImageView and a TextView. Now I handle clicked event by using setOnItemClickListener

```
lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            CategoryInfo cat = (CategoryInfo) lv
                    .getItemAtPosition(position);
            showGameByCategory(Long.valueOf(cat.getId()), cat.getName());
        }
    });
```

When I click on a row, it will start another activity. On that activity, I have a button to go back to the ListView. When click that button, I'll call `Activity.finish();`.

Here's the problem: first time I open ListView and click on any items, it works fine and open new activity. But when I click button back and go back to ListView, I can't click to any items. My app have many tabs, if I switch to another tab and switch back to the ListView, I can click ListView item again. But anytime I click button back, the items are unclickable.

I test on 2 different OS and it works normally on Android 2.3 but this error occurred on Android 4.0.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: this is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_selector_odd"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="10dip"
            android:layout_height="15dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you do in `onResume`?

Comment: @userSeven7s: I did nothing. Like I said, this only occurred on android 4.0. On 2.3 it works fine

Comment: build with the target set to 4.0 and see if it still happens

Comment: Yes it still happens. I wonder maybe when comeback to ListView, some option of the ListView has been wrong so I try to make some change on  `onResume` method but I don't know what to change.

Comment: try launching some other activity in onclick.. to see if its the launched activity that does something

Comment: In `onResume` I set `lv.clearFocus();`, then when go back the first time, I can click the items 1 more time. The next time go back, it not responding again. Do you know why?

Comment: use `android:decendentFocusablity=blocksDescendants` on item layout to prevent item's children(imageview and textview) from getting focus..

Comment: I edit my question to add my layout. Where should I put `android:decendentFocusablity=blocksDescendants` ?

Comment: you can do without the relativelayout.. Just a linearlayout with childs... add the `descendentFocusabilty` to `LinearLayout`...

Comment: did you change the layout? remove the relativeLayout..

Comment: Yes I do. It didn't change a thing.

Comment: Do you have clicklisteners for any of the item's children?

Comment: No. Like I said this only occurred on Android 4.0. I think it has something related to the different between 4.0 and 2.3. Does OnItemClickListener work well in 4.0?

Comment: it is something related to focus.. check where the focus is when you return back to the list.. use findfocus()

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. But in `onResume`, I've already clear focus. But it only affected the first time.

Comment: I use `findfocus()` and print the View. Here is it `android.widget.ListView@41562528`

Comment: set the background to white to this view... so that u know which view.. cant make out by looking at id

Comment: Did you succeed in fixing this issue?

Comment: Yes. I don't use setOnItemClickListener anymore

Comment: use rowview.onClickListener() instead of listview.onClickListener() in your custom adapter

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as you. Even stranger, it happened on some tablet 4.0 or 4.1, while it didn't happen on a phone 4.1.
Using "descendentFocusabilty=blocksDescendants" didn't solve it.

Following the idea of user1603602, I ask for the invalidation of Views of the list (hence a redraw of elements of the list) each time the View becomes visible:

```
@Override
protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
        list.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```

As it reloads each items of the list, it can be annoying if you load images with animations for example, but it solves the problem, and it keep the scrolled position.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just figured out a way to solve it. Remove the listview, then add it back. This will force the view to refresh to the original working state.

for example if your `ListView lv` is on a `LinearLayout lout`

```
 lout.removeView(lv);
 lout.addView(lv);
```

make sure you call this from the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257357/listview-haswindowfocus-true-but-child-views-haswindowfocus-false)

I used a custom adapter containing an array of Views. Within getView(position, ...), I return the View at the specified position. Apparently, ListView didn't like this and sometimes (platform specific) recycles views that shouldn't be recycled.