# android setOnItemClickListener not respond when comes back from another activity

Tags: android, listview, back

I have a listview in my activity.
first time I click listview item, it works fine.
when I press back button and comes back to this activity, I can't click on the item anymore.
this listview works fine with android2.
when i test with android 4, happens this problem.

I found this kind of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184987/android-listview-items-not-responding-when-come-back-from-another-activity), and I've tried all 'descendentFocusabilty' thing,
but not solved yet.
I know i shouldn't post almost same question. but i couldn't find any answer works fine there.

please help me solve this problem.

here is my child1 activity

```
public class TabChild1 extends NavigationActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabchild1);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

     adapter.add("red");
     adapter.add("green");
     adapter.add("blue");
     ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
                String item = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(TabChild1.this, TabChild2.class);
                int iNum = position;
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                goNextHistory("TabChild2", intent);   
            }
        });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

here is my NavigationActivity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends Activity {
public void goNextHistory(String id, Intent intent) {
    NavigationGroupActivity parent = ((NavigationGroupActivity) getParent());
    View view = parent.group.getLocalActivityManager()
            .startActivity(id,intent)
            .getDecorView();
    parent.group.replaceView(view);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    NavigationGroupActivity parent = ((NavigationGroupActivity) getParent());
    parent.back();
}
```

}

here is my NavigationGroupActivity

public class NavigationGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

```
ArrayList<View> history; 
NavigationGroupActivity group;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    history = new ArrayList<View>();
    group = this;
}

public void changeView(View v) {
    history.remove(history.size() - 1);
    history.add(v);
    setContentView(v);
}

public void replaceView(View v) {
    history.add(v);
    setContentView(v);
}

public void back() {
    if(history.size() > 1) {
        history.remove(history.size() - 1);
        setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    group.back();
    return;
}
```

}

and my child1 layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

i think You have to use ***finish()*** inside the onBackPressed() method of class TabChild1. and comment the line ***parent.back()***  inside the onBackPressed() method of class NavigationActivity.
  I think this will work for you.

Comment: thanks, SAURABH_12.
I followed your advice,but unfortunately it didn't work.
do you have any other possible solution?